# Разработка WinForms под Windows из под macOS

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Задача - написать курсовой на .NET Framework. Можно ли на iMac написать C#+WinForms приложение или через VirtualBox ставить винду?

Comment: Первая ссылка с гугла: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566777/how-to-run-a-windows-forms-application-on-macos

Comment: Повтавьте виртуальную машину, на нее винду и готово. Писать можно прямо в макоси, а запускать на виртуалке.